# How to use the spread operator with ArrayList in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jvm

I've read the documentation and I run into this issue of using the spread operator with an ArrayList Collection, and I want to know how to solve the mismatch type or implement a way to use it with ArrayList
I'll attach an image of the code along with the code.

```
fun howSum(targetSum: Int, numbers: ArrayList<Int>): ArrayList<Int>? {
    if (targetSum == 0) return arrayListOf();
    if (targetSum < 0) return null;

    for (number: Int in numbers){
        val remainder = targetSum - number;
        val remainderResult = howSum(remainder, numbers);
        if (remainderResult != null){
            return arrayListOf(*remainderResult, number)
        }
    }

    return null
}
```

[image]

Any comment could be helpful...

Comment: What is your algorithm trying to calculate? Usually you can do everything with `List`. `ArrayList` and the spread operator are probably not the best options here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give us more information about what you are trying to do for a better answer.

The spread operator is for passing an array in place of a `varargs` argument, but you can't add additional arguments to the array at the same time.

If you want a new `ArrayList` that contains the contents of another `ArrayList` with an extra element added, you can do something like this:

```
fun main() {
    val foo = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3)
    val bar = arrayListOf<Int>().apply {
        addAll(foo)
        add(4)
    }
    println(foo)
    println(bar)
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But it's not efficient, because it copies all the items of `foo` into `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Spread operator is not applicable to `List`s, it's intended only for arrays:

```kotlin
fun howSum(targetSum: Int, numbers: ArrayList<Int>): IntArray? {
    if (targetSum == 0) return intArrayOf()
    if (targetSum < 0) return null

    for (number: Int in numbers) {
        val remainder = targetSum - number;
        val remainderResult = howSum(remainder, numbers);
        if (remainderResult != null) {
            return intArrayOf(*remainderResult, number)
        }
    }

    return null
}
```

If you want to create new `List` of the other one with addition of some element, you can use `+` operator:

```
fun howSum(targetSum: Int, numbers: ArrayList<Int>): List<Int>? {
    if (targetSum == 0) return arrayListOf();
    if (targetSum < 0) return null;

    for (number: Int in numbers){
        val remainder = targetSum - number;
        val remainderResult = howSum(remainder, numbers);
        if (remainderResult != null){
            return remainderResult + number
        }
    }

    return null
}
```